# NGINX, wait for proxy if not available

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have a NGINX set up with reverse_proxy and caching (only caching multiple requests for very short time). The backend nginx calls is running locally (reverse proxy address is localhost:8092). 
The backend sometimes needs to restart which takes it offline for a duration of ~2-3 seconds. Currently, nginx serves a 502 for this time. I would prefer stalling requests for that time. 
Is it possible to configure nginx that it waits in case of a 502 and retries periodically?

I know that this is not the cleanest way to solve this but this is not a production system so that this (if possible) appears to be the simplest solution.

The system is running Ubuntu 16.04LTS with nginx 1.10.3

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so.  Nginx will try all available upstreams and if they are not responding will provide a 502 (Gateway error).  The documentation from the Nginx upstream says:

> If an error occurs during communication with a server, the request will be passed to the next server, and so on until all of the functioning servers will be tried. If a successful response could not be obtained from any of the servers, the client will receive the result of the communication with the last server.

Source: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html#upstream